JBeret job execution start time not constant?
I have some JSR352 jobs running in Wildfly (which uses JBeret). Some time ago I noticed strange behaviour, and now I drilled it down to something that's puzzling me.
So far I assumed the job execution start time to be constant. Once the job is started this should no longer change, right? So I assumed this expression to deliver a constant value as long as the jobContext does not refer to another execution id:
BatchRuntime.getJobOperator().getJobExecution(jobContext.getExecutionId()).getStartTime()

Now the puzzling bit: Although the job execution id does not change (I verified), all of a sudden the start time is reported to be different. It looks like after the fourth step in my batch the execution time resets to the current time, which is then constant again for the next four steps.
This has no impact on the execution itself but the execution time reporting that I added via listeners. Also worth knowing is that this only happens sporadically on one of my jobs.
What can be the reasons or conditions that cause the execution's start time to change?

Please create a jira issue to document the details and track it.
